# Share code (which uses an abstract operation) between two classes

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, software-design

I'm developping a server application in Java. The server need two type of server classes. These classes have some methods in common, the code in these methods is exactly the same. So i create an abstract super-class containing all the shared code, and both classes are inheriting it. But, there is some part of the code that need to be precised by subclasses. I mean that the superclass "rely" on subclasses methods.

Here is a purified example of what i mean:

```
public abstract class AbstractServer
{
    public void loadConfig(String configPath)
    {
        //Load the configuration file.

        //This code is exactly the same for subclasses.
    }

    public void startRMI(int port)
    {
        //Create an empty RMI registry.
        //This part also need to be identical.

        //Here' where the superclass "rely" on subclasses.
        fillRegistry(); //Call the method overwritten by subclasses.
    }

    /**
    Bind remote objects in the RMI registry
    */
    protected abstract void fillRegistry(); //This method will be overriten by subclasses.
}
```

I feel that it's really bad to make it like that, but i can't find another cleaner way to do it.

So, what i want is some advice on how i could make it better.

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: for starters, I'd make fillRegistry() protected, unless it needs to be called externally and you should add abstract to class declaration for SuperClass (which I feel is better named as ServerBase or AbstractServer or something like that)

Comment: and the superclass must be abstract but other than that and making the method protected, I don't see anything wrong with the design.

Comment: Ok, because i found an article about the Swing API. And the author said that it's a bad thing that JComponent rely on the method "paintComponent" of subclasses. So i wanted to know if it's that bad to do it.

Comment: overall it's OK but you should make the startRMI method final to prevent that the behavior gets overridden in a subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is just fine. Stick with it buddy.

I feel your 'philosophical need' to understand it. Base class 'relying' on the subclass is fine as long as the base class is abstract. It knows that some things have to be registered at this point, but it doesn't have the faintest clue about what exactly to be registered. So the high-level process is encoded in the base class with 'holes' that can be plugged in by the derived class. The high level process and the position of the 'hole' itself is valuable and this justifies the implementation of the base class. The derived classes just follow the fundamental OO principle of 'coding by difference' and plugs the 'holes'.

Answer (score 0):

Looks about right to me after your edits  (assuming that you left out the Exception throwing part for readability) :)

All three methods would need to raise exceptions in a real world case.

Comment: Yes, i make the example free of inessentials things for comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Super class is inherited by sub-class. You can write methods in super class which you want to make common and leave it untouched. For the other part of code which you want it to be overwritten by sub classes define other set of methods in super class. write methods in sub-classes also. when u call method from sub-class u can put to call super-class method's

in short u have to write methods in sub class to over write the methods of superclass.

Answer (score 0):

I would also make sure that your superclass is actually abstract.  In this snippet it isn't.  Overall though, looks decent.

Also consider declaring any instance variables in your superclass that classes that extend it will need as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is nothing wrong with requiring subclasses' implementation in abstract (base) classes. It's just something that should not get abused, IMO. However, if I had to avoid it, I would make the ServerClass **not** abstract at all, and define every method of it. Instead, I would create RegistryFactory classes and pass them to the ServerClass :

```
class ServerClass {
   public void startRMI(int port, RegistryFactory rf) {
      // ...
      rf.fillRegistry(this);
   }
}


interface RegistryFactory {
   /**
    * Implement this method
    */
   public void fillRegistry(ServerClass server);
}

public class RMIRegistryFactory implements RegistryFactory {
   public void fillRegistry(ServerClass server) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Or something like that.

Comment: But wouldn't it be the Poltergeist antipattern? I instanciate a "RMIRegistryFactory" just to fill the server, and then it is garbage-collected? Because i like your idea, it would really lighten my subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine, but it needs a simple improvement to make it perfect - make the `startRMI()` method `final`:

```
public final void startRMI(int port) {
    fillRegistry();
}
```

This way you will prevent that someone overrides it (maybe because of not knowing that everything in `startRMI()` should be reused and that only `fillRegistry()` has to be customized).

Your solution generally matches the [template method design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

> The template method is a method in a superclass, usually an abstract
>   superclass, and defines the skeleton of an operation in terms of a
>   number of high-level steps. These steps are themselves implemented by
>   additional helper methods in the same class as the template method.
>
> The helper methods may be either abstract methods, for which case
>   subclasses are required to provide concrete implementations, or hook
>   methods, which have empty bodies in the superclass. **Subclasses can
>   (but are not required to) customize the operation by overriding the
>   hook method**s. The intent of the template method is to define the
>   overall structure of the operation, **while allowing subclasses to
>   refine, or redefine, certain steps**. (Wikipedia)

Given the above, the method `startRMI()` is a template method which defines the skeleton of an operation by using a number of high-level steps (in your case it's only one step but this doesn't make a difference). The method `fillRegistry()` in your example is a high-level step - it's defined as an abstract method in the superclass and has a concrete implementation in the superclasses.

On the other side, if you would override the method `startRMI()` in a subclass, this would not be OK anymore. That's why you should make it `final` to avoid confusion - this way someone who creates a subclass will know that he must implement `fillRegistry()` (since it's abstract) but should not change the implementation of `startRMI` (since it's final).

Since this is a commonly used design pattern, I wouldn't worry at all if this solution is OK, a lot of people are doing it like that and everyone who knows design patterns will recognize it, I think it feels very natural even for developers who don't know the design pattern.